# jQuery convert curl to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

I am trying to convert a `curl` command to an `ajax` call but I keep getting a bad request. Here is my `curl`:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  \"first_name\": \"Bob\",
  \"last_name\": \"Dole\",
  \"address\": {
    \"street_number\": \"123\",
    \"street_name\": \"apple st.\",
    \"city\": \"Miami Beach\",
    \"state\": \"FL\",
    \"zip\": \"33140\"
  }
}" "http://api.reimaginebanking.com/customers?key=bb67d82asdr32r93927282920159874"
```

I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.reimaginebanking.com/customers?key=bb67d82asdr32r93927282920159874",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
        first_name: "Bob",
        last_name: "Dole",
        address: {
            street_number: "123",
            street_name: "apple st.",
            city: "Miami Beach",
            state: "NJ",
            zip: "33141"
        },
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

I get this error: `400 (Bad Request)`. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Try to add `dataType: "json"`

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: `error: (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => { console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); }`, what do you get in your console?

Comment: It says `error Bad Request`.

Comment: And if go to the network tab of your inspector, and try to see the server's response? -- If I try running this I get a 401 Unauthorized. (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRxKGv)

Comment: @choz Thank you. Stringifying worked perfectly. Since you removed your comment, I did: `data: JSON.stringify({first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Dole", address: {street_number: "123", street_name: "apple st.", city: "Miami Beach", state: "NJ", zip: "33141"}, })`.